# Can't fix my script to log the way I need it

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So this is really getting on my nerves. I needed to explain this a bit better so here it is. I'm trying to make my script log in google's console a specific way. I've got some images to help explain.. Let's hop on in.

So first, this is how it's currently logging.. Which is good so far. I'm happy with this. It's not one big array, nice and neat. 
Image below:
(https://i.gyazo.com/81fc8d76b34a81f4fff7fc23e94f1bf1.png)

So this is the last log emitted(You can see in the image above.) It's just edited to the way I need it to log:
`[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]`

So I'm trying to make all the logs send just like that.^^ Replacing the spaces between each pair with a comma, and adding "[" and "]" to each pair.

So how I would like it to log:
(Really helps)
(https://i.gyazo.com/af179df0b2ce93f018809f6921bce59a.png)

My script:

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "http://myurl.com/someURLWITH.svg");

xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
this.responseText.trim(),
"image/svg+xml"
);

const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));

var Lines = (polylines.map( pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(
pair => pair.split(',').map(x=>+x),

console.log("[" + pl.getAttribute('points') + "]")
)
));
});
xhr.send();
```

Keep in mind!!! I don't want it to be one big array!!!! The way it logs each one separately is perfect.. I just need to change the way it logs each one.

So in my code you can see `console.log("[" + pl.getAttribute('points') + "]")` I've tried to making it like this `console.log("[" + pl.getAttribute("[" + 'points' + "]") + "]")` really praying this would do the trick but I was wrong. Like always.

So yeah, simply instead of it logging like this `[346,453 346,452 346,452 346,453 346,453 347,453 347,453 347,454 348,454 349,454 350,454 351,454 352,454 353,454 354,454 354,453 355,452 355,453]`
...  I would like it to log just like this `[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]` Thank you.

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code - it's next to unreadable with comments becoming code etc, and absolutely no indentation

Comment: Had no idea what you were trying to say about it becoming code? I've fixed it as much as I possibly could... Even tho it wasn't that hard to read in the first place....

Comment: Still no indentation, no wonder you're having trouble if you write code with no indentation ... where you currently have the console.log, and what it is logging, is absolutely meaningless, since it is logging the unprocessed `points` attribute

Comment: `Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'), pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair => pair.split(',').map(Number))).forEach(line => console.log(JSON.stringify(line)));`

Comment: You're a genius. Thank you.

Comment: I know I am, my mother had me tested

Comment: Could you help me one more time? After that I'll be on my way forever. I should of tagged you in it already. If you could help me with that last piece. That'll be glorious.

Comment: If you can't that's fine as well. I'm just glad I got a little bit of help at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was almost there, but what you were logging to the console was ridiculous, since it was just the points attribute, unmodified

So, something like this

```
const polylines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'));
const Lines = polylines.map(pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair => pair.split(',').map(Number)));

Lines.forEach(line => console.log(JSON.stringify(line)));
```

Or, given that the second argument to Array.from is a map function, you can further simplify the code to

```
const Lines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'), pl => pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair => pair.split(',').map(Number)));

Lines.forEach(line => console.log(JSON.stringify(line)));
```

Note, the console.log is done AFTER the processing

as for the comment

```
Lines.forEach(line => {
    // here you can post each line to whatever you need
});
```

Comment: I have one more question. Using this current script you guys helped me with.. https://jsfiddle.net/p9Ly258f/ I now simply need to do this one last thing. Send that data as a post request.... So it'll send each data piece as a post request.. Again thank you guys. I was stressing out on this stuff.

Comment: @Hex - added a suggestion for posting

Comment: !? I don't see it anywhere??

Comment: Well, I don't know how you intend on posting the lines somewhere, so the very end of the answer, there's a comment ... `// here you can post each line to whatever you need` - I know you're new to javascript, but that doesn't mean you can't write the required code yourself (or at least try, and if you have an issue, post another question on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

please try this, maybe this will work for you.

```
var dt = "346 453 346 452 346 452 346 453 346 453 347 453 347 453 347 454 348 454 349 454 350 454 351 454 352 454 353 454 354 454 354 453 355 452 355 453";

function fnGetObject(data) {
    var objList = [];
    var obList = data.split(' ');

    var obResult = []
    for (var i = 0; i < obList.length; i += 2) {
        obResult.push([parseInt(obList[i]), parseInt(obList[i + 1])]);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obResult);
}

console.log(fnGetObject(dt));
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm pretty sure I've said I need it to log like this ``[[346,453],[346,452],[346,452],[346,453],[346,453],[347,453],[347,453],[347,454],[348,454],[349,454],[350,454],[351,454],[352,454],[353,454],[354,454],[354,453],[355,452],[355,453]]`` Besides, this code you gave me can't parse the SVG from the URL....

Comment: ``["348", "454"]``. It also has a space after the comma.

Comment: why the emphasis on the exact layout of the console.log? it's informational, nothing more

Comment: If you could make it log just like that example ^^^^ that'll be beautiful. Here's what I've said in my question. ``So I'm trying to make all the logs send just like that.^^ Replacing the spaces between each pair with a comma, and adding "[" and "]" to each pair.``

Comment: Oh now that's what I'm talking about! Now only if it can parse all of points using that URL containing the URL.

Comment: Can you make it read the points attribute of the SVG and log them all like that??? If so my question would be fulfilled and finished!

Comment: @Hex, really? you can't figure out how to adapt that code to your requirements?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've just stared learning JavaScript about a month ago lol. I do suck at it.